# JQuery appendTo Div with ID instead of appendTo('body')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this code :

```
config.$leftnavbutton = $('<img src="' + config.defaultbuttons.leftnav[0] + '" id="btnlnav" >')
    .css({
        zIndex: 50, 
        position: 'absolute', 
        left: config.offsets.left + config.defaultbuttons.leftnav[1] + 'px', 
        top: config.offsets.top + config.defaultbuttons.leftnav[2] + 'px', 
        cursor: 'hand', 
        cursor: 'pointer'
    })
    .attr({ title: '' })
    .appendTo('body')
```

the code inserts an image at the end of body. i want it to insert it at the end of

```
<div id="slider-container">
```

is there any way? thanks!

Comment: `.appendTo('#slider-container')` - you'll save yourself some time and learn a thing or two if you take up the habit of checking the [jQuery API pages](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Comment: you should have posted this as an answer so i could make it complete..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this

```
.appendTo('#slider-container')
```

Please try this and let me know if works or not.

Comment: thanks. it worked. also you're the 2nd to say that lol; Mr @Pointy was the first ;)
thank you guys all you saved me time of reading JQuery API pages cause i am not into that as for now :)

Comment: If it worked, please make it completed.

It will give both of us some points.